# Clear WebGL Canvas, Three.JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I'm working with the WebGLRenderer in three.js and I'm unable to clear the canvas. Basically, I have a method that keeps adding another object to the scene, but clears the children out before being added. For instance

```
group = new THREE.Object3D();

function add(object){
    group.children = [];//clears the group children first
    group.add(object);
}
```

I figured that this would let it clear, but I was wrong. I'm used to canvasrendering doing this for me. Does anybody know how I should go about clearing the WebGL canvas?

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer, look for `.clear()` function.

Comment: I was using that to no avail.

Comment: group.remove(group.children);

Answer (score 2):

Clearing the canvas and clearing a subtree of the scene graph are two different things.

Clearing the canvas can be accomplished by `renderer.clear()`, assuming your `THREE.WebGLRenderer` is named `renderer`.

Clearing a subtree of the scene graph can be accomplished by `group.remove.apply(group, group.children)` or (in modern JavaScript) `group.remove(...group.children)`. It is not recommended to merely assign a new array to `group.children`, as this messes with the internals. Add using `group.add(object)` and remove using `group.remove(object)`.